# How do I get enough to pay off that second loan?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

While I have fun playing Recettear on steam, I am having a hell of a time paying that second loan off. I've game-overed twice by now and I actually have no idea how to go about it.

If I put high priced objects on display, many customers (especially the little girl, the husband, and Louis) aren't willing or able to even afford a 10% raise. In fact, when Louis asked to buy metal armor, he wasn't able to pay the reduced  price of 80%. Man, Louis, I'm trying to make a living here!

But with low priced objects, I will never get the necessary 30k in a week. Also, I've noticed that the more often I open my shop, the fewer customers come in.

What am I doing wrong and how can I attract customers with bigger budgets so that I can sell them my highpriced wares?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, one very important aspect of the game that many people tend to overlook is the fact that is has a "looping" feature. There's no notification in the game at all that this exists, and personally, I found out completely by accident. When you get a "Game Over," the month restarts. **However**, you restart the month with all the Merchant Levels, Adventurer Levels, stock, pix, dungeon levels you unlocked with your previous attempt! You'll have to make your way through the Hall of Trials again, but after that, I *believe* you should be able to continue from the last door area again. For example, I had dungeon levels 6-11 unlocked of Jade Way during my first attempt at the second week, I got a game over, then when I restarted, I still had access to those levels. So don't stress too much about failing, just keep on trucking and don't reload your game if you want to keep your progress.

The number of customers coming in isn't really directly related to how often you open your shop. You get the peak amount of customers coming in around noon/afternoon. Business (like a real shop) is a slower in the morning and evening. So don't worry about being open "too often."

Dungeon crawling is the most optimal way to stock your shelves. Getting to the end of the dungeon means you get to take home everything instead of only one thing if you die.  So survivability is your goal! Memorizing the attack patterns of the different types of enemies is definitely a good idea. If you do that, you can fairly easily get through the dungeons without taking too much damage. You can also run through the dungeons avoiding everything to get to the final boss, but you won't have as much loot to take home, so it's usually better to just kill stuff. There's also a Chain bonus which gives you bonus XP for killing monsters of the same type and color. I'm not sure if/when that bonus maxes out. It's a good way to level up your adventurer though, as well as farm on respawning enemies for some loot. Take at least one health recovery item to use in an emergency and remember, your health completely replenishes when you level. Don't rush the final bosses, take your time and watch their attack pattern if it's your first time fighting them.

The best way to get your customers to buy larger purchases is to build a better relationship with them. Customers also effectively have "levels," and whenever you sell to them, it helps go towards leveling up their relationship with you, which in turn increases their budget.  Getting "Just Chains" will level up your merchant level quickly, which is when you sell something to someone without haggling.  It starts out at 2XP and doing that several times in a row will give you an XP bonus up to 128 XP. This will help level up your Merchant Level quicker, which will in turn give you better options for handling your store! There is also apparently a mechanic ingame where you will gain more rep with the customer if you sell to them around or exactly at the price they were thinking of. So in general, if you're selling at a profit of 110% on a first offer rather than haggling them down to 120% after a first offer of 140%, you'll end up with better XP/Rep gain overall, even if in the short term, it's less profit.

Hope these tips help! Good luck and Capitalism, Ho!

Comment: Great advice, thanks. I read around a bit and actually found that the game leads you on a totally false trail by telling you that 130% selling is the right way to go. I now sell most items for 104% to 105% percent (sometimes 110%) and way more people are coming to the shop each time I open up and are way more willing to spend large amounts of money.

I wish that Steam would have the instruction booklet included, as I'm pretty sure that things like customer hearts et. al. that are never mentioned in the game, will be described there.

Answer (score 3):

For one, every customer has a budget and they can't spend more than that no matter how low a % it is.

Old vase won't be sold for anywhere near it's price until you get some reputation....

Try to aim for 104% selling 70% buying and you will usually get nearly the price they want... and sell items with +   (the exact price goes up if it's on the shelf or if it's doubled price) If you keep it up eventually they will show a nice heart <3 <3 <3  that means your rep went up with that customer.

The higher the rep the higher the budget, first <3 gives them 10 times the budget, after that it is a good deal less.... but once you get a bunch of hearts, you will be able to sell those higher priced items.

Here are some budgets:

- Little Girl  600
- Louie    1200
- Young Man   1800
- Guild Master   1800
- Old Man   2400
- Charme   2400
- Woman  3600

Those are base with 0 rep